# Migrating a Static HTML/CSS Site to RoR

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an existing website, which is built on top of HTML/CSS/JS.

It has extensive theming, and over 10,000 lines of combined CSS (fancy animations and such).

I would like to move it over into my RoR app, however I cannot just drop it in a view because every import statement will break (that I know).

How can I move a site with many JS and CSS imports over to a RoR application? If I could drop it somewhere and let it just be as a static site that would be best. It just doesn't work because RoR won't accept the paths for my imports.

All help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Um, can't you just refactor rails routing in your views?

Comment: I was hoping somehow I could just include my static site 'as is'. It has about 15 imports, and would be difficult to re route everything.

Comment: Well if you know rails structure, you can't put site as it is. You at least need a controller and his views, and a routes, that're connected to these views.

Comment: actually you can do this fairly easily, as long as all the links in the html are relative, put the site in a subdirectory in the public directory, e.g. /public/foo and it will be accessible via yoursite.com/foo/